# How can I hide versioned targets behind unversioned targets?

Tags: bazel

I'm working on a personal project that involves SDL; I'd like to have SDL's source checked into a third_party directory in my project. My plan is to have something like this:

```
third_party/
  sdl/
    2_0_9/
    2_0_8/
    (etc)
```

I want to be able to have different versions to make upgrading a bit easier. Also I'm curious.

My goal is to have other libraries depend on *unversioned* targets: `//third_party/sdl:sdl` instead of `//third_party/sdl/2_0_9:sdl`, so the particular version is sort of an "implementation detail" of the top-level target.

Is this possible? Can I alias or re-export the versioned target somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [`alias`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#alias) targets in `third_party/sdl/BUILD`:

```
alias(
    name = "sdl",
    actual = "//third_party/sdl/2_0_9:sdl",
)
```

You can then refer to this target as `//third_party/sdl` or `//third_party/sdl:sdl`.